# Can Visual Studio 2012 run from a RAM drive?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

Can Visual Studio 2012 run from a ram drive instead from the boot drive? I would like it to run super fast. I already use an SSD, have 16G RAM and multi core CPU.

**Update:**

For people wondering if it all fits in RAM, I am planning to upgrade to 32G ram (MB supports up to 128GB ram) if needed. Also my Windows temp folder and asp.net temporary folder are already in the RAM drive.

I am looking for the steps where when the system boots, it copies VS, .NET framework and everything VS needs to run  to the RAM drive.

Would Windows 8 help in any of this setup?

Comment: I've successfully placed a project's intermediate and output directories on a ramdisk.  Of course, disk cache makes access to files stored on a permanent disk almost as fast (excepting the first read after boot, but the data has to get into the ramdisk too somehow)

Comment: @Ben this is a great idea, since those files can be easily restored if there is a powerloss or corrupt memory.  Although cache will be as good as a RAM drive on reads, the ram drive will be much faster for writes when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect all files in Visual Studio folder (symlink) to RAM disk.
Also .NET framework files, as Visual Studio rely heavily on .NET framework.

Comment: I think he knows all that.  The question is, will it all fit on a RAM disk?

Comment: I haven't install 2012 yet, so I can't give you the exact figure. But for past experience in 2010, choose the parts that used most. For example, if you do not develop C++ program, you leave VC folder not symlinked to RAM disk.

Comment: Note that if your TEMP folder is on ram drive, certain functions the requires writing *.sdf (SQL Server Database local file) may fail.